# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

I understand there are questions similar to this issue. And I have taken the time to look through them. But the implementation here is a little different than in some of the cases I looked at. The good news here is my fourth column, the running totals column, is correctly displaying the data I want. Everything is working (correctly calculated and displaying) so why is my app held up on this? I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

[image]

```
calculateRunningTotals(){
        var attendantTotalCell = 0;
        var total = 0;
        var totalCell="";
        var totalsCells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(3)");

        totalsCells.forEach(function(cell, index){
          console.log("The contents of the totals cell " + cell.innerText);
          totalCell = cell.innerText;
          attendantTotalCell = totalCell.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
          total = parseInt(attendantTotalCell) + parseInt(total);
          console.log("Attendant Total Cell is: " + attendantTotalCell);
          console.log("Attendant Total is " + total);
          cell.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = total;
        })
      }
```

Comment: that means `cell.nextElementSibling` is null - i.e. `cell` has no next (element) sibling - based on the image, it looks like each row has only 3 cells, therefore `nth-child(3)` will be the last one - of course, an image doesnt' show hidden cells, you'd need to show the HTML to really get a useful answer - looking again though, I'm wrong about the number of cells in each row

Comment: `nextElementSibling` will return `null` when iterating through the last `cell`, because there is no "next sibling".

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thank you kindly for responding.  And then I place something in that sibling cell.  And you can see that in the screenshot.  So what's up?

Comment: Images are deceptive - can you show the HTML of a row

Comment: @TylerRoper there should be an empty td cell in which I place a value.  As the screenshot shows I am.  So what's the problem?

Comment: The screenshot is very difficult to get anything from. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are A LOT of related questions with the exact same same title (see right panel), did you look through them for relevance to your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following check to ensure that `cell.nextElementSibling` is defined, then this should resolve your problem:

```
calculateRunningTotals(){
    var attendantTotalCell = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var totalCell="";
    var totalsCells = document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(3)");

    totalsCells.forEach(function(cell, index){
      console.log("The contents of the totals cell " + cell.innerText);
      totalCell = cell.innerText;
      attendantTotalCell = totalCell.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, '');
      total = parseInt(attendantTotalCell) + parseInt(total);
      console.log("Attendant Total Cell is: " + attendantTotalCell);
      console.log("Attendant Total is " + total);

      /* Add the following check to ensure nextElementSibling is defined
         before attempting to access it */
      if(cell.nextElementSibling) {
        cell.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = total;
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: that was it.  Thank you for taking the time.  I appreciate it.